# Is dsa_with_SHA256 not supported by OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl

I have been trying to use the simple code given in the OpenSSL page
[MAN page for evp_get_digestbyname](http://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_get_digestbyname) 
Now when I give the message digest as -
dsa_with_SHA256
it tells me 

**Unknown message digest dsa_with_SHA256**
I checked out the code for OpenSSL and did a grep on it just to see if the phrase appears, and it gave me some results which proves that the digest type seems to be there in OpenSSL. Anyone can tell me why it doesn't work? 
Also, https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-notes.html tells us that OpenSSL has support for dsa-with-SHA256.
Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone used it before. Need help.

Comment: DSA usually (in OpenSSL) refers to a type of key (odd, because of the name DSA, I know), not a digest algorithm.  Thus I think you'd want to use `EVP_DigestSignInit` et al, as in this example: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying#Signing_2.  You'd use _e.g._ `EVP_get_digestbyname("sha256")` to get the `EVP_MD`, and then separately you'd load in your DSA key, for that key argument.